# Why am I getting this unexpected result in Eclipse console output? (String comparison)

Tags: java, eclipse

EDIT: I do not think this is a copy of an existing question.  The references of my 2 declared string point at the same memory location, so why is my `==` (reference comparison) giving false?  It is not a character by character comparison.

I am writing test files to get a better understanding of Java String references and comparisons.  I expected the 3rd line of my code to be :

> Should be true: true

Why is it not?

```
   public class testr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String s = "s";
        String t = "s"; 

        System.out.println("String s hashcode: " + s.hashCode());
        System.out.println("String t hashcode: " + t.hashCode());
        System.out.println("Should be true: " + s==t);

    }

}
```

Output:

```
String s hashcode: 115
String t hashcode: 115
false
```

Comment: Doesn't make the output of `false` it pretty clear that your last print statement is evaluated as `("SHould be true: " + s)==t`, rather than `"SHould be true: " + (s==t)`? Thus, use explicit brackets.

Comment: @Tom  ah - that was it. Thanks!